# How to check if an array of references contains a specific reference?

Tags: perl, reference

How can I find whether an array contains a specific reference?

If the array didn't contain references, I'd do something like

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @haystack;
say "in haystack" if exists $hash{$needle};
```

But with e.g. `@haystack=({},{},{})` and `$needle=$haystack[0]`, this casts all those references and the needle to strings. Is that still the recommended approach?

Comment: "If the array contained scalars.. " -> An array can *only* contain scalars. You mean strings, perhaps. You need an extra level of dereferencing.

Comment: @TLP Thanks, I meant "If the array contained non-references". (Unless maybe 1 is considered a string?)

Comment: You might consider clarifying your title. You mean perhaps if an array of references contains a specific hash key?

Comment: @TLP I mean that $needle is a reference, e.g. HASH(0x1111111), and I want to find if that reference also lies in `@haystack`, which consists only of references.

Comment: Oh, I see... perhaps you should clarify that `$needle = { some_key => "some_value" }` in your code..

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4064001/725418)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare references numerically:

```
say "in haystack" if grep $_ == $needle, @haystack;
```

As references are converted to their numerical address in this context, they will both return the same number. There is of course a chance that a number or a string can convert to the same number, so if you are in doubt as to whether your argument is a reference, you might want to check that. E.g.

```
for (@haystack) {
    next unless ref($_) eq ref($needle);
    say "in haystack", last if $_ == $needle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use references as hash keys, but remember that they are converted to strings before they are added to the hash and you cannot use them as references again.

Code like this works fine.

```
use v5.10;
use warnings;

my %a = (a => 1);
my %b = (b => 1);
my %c = (c => 1);
my %d = (d => 1);

my @haystack = \(%a, %b, %c);

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @haystack;
say "in haystack" if exists $hash{\%c};
```

Comment: Yes. ("this casts all those references and the needle to strings.") That makes me wonder if it's really the best solution, so I asked this question to see whether that's the canonical solution to this problem.

Comment: @Andreas: It really depends on the bigger picture. There may be a better way, depending on the nature of your data.

Comment: I'm not worried about time or memory usage.